# swift protocol extension default implementation vs actual implementation in class

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Consider the following code:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    static var name: String { get }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    static var name: String {
        return "unnamed"
    }
}

// does not specify its own name
class MyClass: MyProtocol {

}

//specifies its own name!
class MyClass2: MyProtocol {
    static var name: String {
        return "Specific name"
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
print("\(MyClass.name)")
//>>"unnamed"

let myClass2 = MyClass2()
print("\(MyClass2.name)")
//>>"Specific name"
```

Does swift guarantee that for classes (such as in this case MyClass2) that have an actual implementation of a protocol property, in this case "name", that this is used from the class, and not the one of the default "name" implementation via the protocol extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having a default implementation for a required protocol function/property means that your conforming types won't have to implement that function/property, they can use the default implementation instead.

However, if a conforming type does implement the function/property, then the compiler will always call the more specific implementation, namely the one in your conforming class and not the default one.

So even if you stored an instance of `MyClass2` in a variable of type `MyProtocol`, you'd still get the `MyClass2` implementation when accessing the property on the variable.

```
let myClass2: MyProtocol = MyClass2()
type(of: myClass2).name // "Specific name"
```

The behaviour is different for non-required properties/functions declared and defined in a protocol extension. If you declare a property/function in the protocol extension only, then even if you provide a different implementation for that in a conforming class, you won't be able to access that implementation from a variable whose type is the protocol type rather than the specific conforming type.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    static var name: String { get }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    static var name: String {
        return "unnamed"
    }

    // Optional protocol requirement
    static var nonRequired: String {
        return "nonRequired"
    }
}

// does not specify its own name
class MyClass: MyProtocol { }

//specifies its own name!
class MyClass2: MyProtocol {
    static var name: String {
        return "Specific name"
    }

    // Specific implementation
    static var nonRequired: String {
        return "Specific"
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
MyClass.name

let myClass2: MyProtocol = MyClass2()
type(of: myClass2).name // "Specific name"
type(of: myClass2).nonRequired // "nonRequired"
MyClass2.nonRequired // "Specific"
```

Comment: 1. What is the difference of `type(of: myClass2).nonRequired` and `MyClass2.nonRequired`? 2. Are now two functions with the same name on that type?